How did Ancient Greek πτ become φ (ph)?
How did Ancient Greek πτ become φ (ph): κρύπτω / κρύφω?

If I remember correctly, it was the other way round: φ became π in front of the suffix -τ-.

The root of κρύπτω is actually κρυφ-, with an aspirated consonant—we can see this in the perfect forms, like κέκρυφα. But Ancient Greek didn't allow sequences of stops with different voicings: they all take the voicing of the last one in the sequence, so you get βδ, πτ, φθ, not πδ, φτ, βθ, and so on.
Presumably, the Koine form κρύφω came from some form without the τ suffix, so the underlying aspirated φ shows through.

This is true as far as it goes, but here πτ results not from *pht but from *phy. The combination of any labial stop + *y regularly gives πτ.

This is not part of the question, to be sure, but, in Modern Greek phonology, the Ancient Greek πτ & κτ have shifted to φτ (εφτά, φτερά) & χτ (νύχτα, χτίσμα). Would this shift fit with the above?

LSJ write:  “κρύφω late form of κρύπτω, only impf”. This imperfect looks like it is a back-formation from the aorist with -ps-.

Why would an aorist in -ps- form the basis of an analogical change from -p- to -ph- when neither -ps- nor -pt- is able to distinguish aspiration in the first member? Surely the perfect, which actually has surface -φ- would be a more obvious candidate.
